# BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException even when file IS actually there

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a simple app to take a picture. this is my code

```
Button b1;
ImageView iv;
String TAG = "MAIN ACTIVITY";

File photo;
private Uri mImageUri;


private File createTemporaryFile(String part, String ext) throws Exception {


    File externalStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File tempDir = new File(externalStorageDirectory + "/cameratest/");
    if (!tempDir.exists()) {
        tempDir.mkdir();

    }
    return File.createTempFile(part, ext, tempDir);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

            try {
                // place where to store camera taken picture
                photo = createTemporaryFile("picture", ".jpg");
                photo.delete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Can't create file to take picture!");
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please check SD card! Image shot is impossible!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            mImageUri = Uri.fromFile(photo);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mImageUri);

            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


    if (requestCode == 0 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {



        Log.d(TAG, mImageUri.toString());
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mImageUri.toString());
        iv.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    }


}
```

as you can see i've added `eLog.d(TAG, mImageUri.toString());` at the end and in the logcat (as well as the `FileNotFoundException`) i see this direcory:

```
03-27 00:43:30.498 30526-30526/myapplication.example.falcoleo.cameratest1 D/MAIN ACTIVITY: file:///storage/emulated/0/cameratest/picture459838058.jpg
03-27 00:43:30.499 30526-30526/myapplication.example.falcoleo.cameratest1 E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/storage/emulated/0/cameratest/picture459838058.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

guess if this directory exists? 
**spoler alert**, [it does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZFNe.png). And it's not like the image is created after the `BitmapFactory.decodeFile`. I really do not understand what i'm doing wrong. Everything works fine except when it actually has to display the photo, then it just does not display it. just blank. Like WTF m8 i'm just trying to do my job no need to go crazy, you know.

Comment: are you sure that you have permissions to read/write in external memory?

Comment: i have permissions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace `mImageUri.toString()` with `mImageUri.getPath()`.

`decodeFile` expects a path, not an uri string.

Answer (score 8):

```
file:///storage/emulated/0/cameratest/picture459838058.jpg
```

Remove `file://` because the decodeFile() expects a file system path.

```
/storage/emulated/0/cameratest/picture459838058.jpg
```

Comment: ok it works. I used `string.replace("file://","")` is there a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 2):

Use BitmapFactory.decodeStream instead of BitmapFactory.decodeFile.

```
try ( InputStream is = new URL( file_url ).openStream() ) {
  Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream( is );
}
```

Source https://stackoverflow.com/a/28395036/5714364

Answer (score 0):

Ok for me it was the file path was wrong so I needed to get the real filepath.

**First**

```
File file = new File(getPath(uri));

public String getPath (Uri uri)
{
    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri,
                                               projection,
                                               null,
                                               null,
                                               null);
    if (cursor == null)
        return null;
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String s = cursor.getString(column_index);
    cursor.close();
    return s;
}
```

**Then Back To Uri**

```
Uri newUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

This conversion to file and back to uri did the trick for me.  I was receiving simple data from action.SEND.

Comment: there are many other elaborate systems to get the file path, but this is the direction that some of you may need to go in... I just posted a simple one (copied and pasted from somewhere else) to just show my point of view in a simple way