# How to get path from image on drawable folder and set as image view, Bitmap?

Tags: android, image, bitmap, path, android-drawable

I already have some pictures on my drawable folder from android project.

I create some objects (Agents) and then I need to set the `imageView` with this picture I saved on database.

So, I am saving the picture as `String photoPath`:

```
Uri path1 = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID+"/" + R.drawable.agent1);
        String photoAg1 = path1.getPath();
ag1.setPhotoPath(photoAg1);
```

(I have already tried path1.toString.)

Ok, no problems until there.
This object is shown at a `listView` with `ImageView`.

To show it there, I am doing:

```
    ImageView photo = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_cell_photo);
System.out.println(agent.getPhotoPath());                    
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(agent.getPhotoPath());
                    Bitmap lowdefbitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap,300,300,true);

                    photo.setImageBitmap(lowdefbitmap);
```

The problem is on the `createScaledBitmap`.
Error above:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.graphics.Bitmap.getWidth()' on a null object reference
                                                                   at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:714)
```

Return from the `System.out.println`: /2131099732
If I put `path1.toString` the return is: android.resource://com.aa.xlambton/2131099732

Ive already took a look at:
[Create a Bitmap/Drawable from file path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804404/create-a-bitmap-drawable-from-file-path)

[Android get image path from drawable as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8601070/android-get-image-path-from-drawable-as-string)

[Get absolute path of android drawable image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25758159/get-absolute-path-of-android-drawable-image/25758286#25758286)

[BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException even when file IS actually there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242457/bitmapfactory-unable-to-decode-stream-java-io-filenotfoundexception-even-when)

I think I am saving this path wrong, because `Bitmap` cannot decode the file, so it is going empty to `createdScaledBitmap`.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: do u want to convert drawable as bitmap? why do u need it? just simply set the drawable as image resource

Comment: Possible duplicate of this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save **Reference Id** `R.drawable.img_name` as integer rather than saving path.

When you need to manipulate this drawable you can use that id instead of  `R.drawable.img_name`.

If you need a bitmap from this drawable follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035692/how-to-convert-a-drawable-to-a-bitmap)

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                                       saved_id);
```

Comment: I have new agents also and I need to save pictures took from the user, can I get the reference from the photo taken also?

Comment: No. In that case you will need to have image path.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use this method:

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.youResourceId);
```

Answer (score 0):

try like this

```
public int getImage(String imageName) {

    int drawableResourceId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(imageName, "drawable", context.getPackageName());

    return drawableResourceId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my project, I want to get some images from project folder. So there is a way to get your images in java class, however it is simple in .xml file. it is clearly done by assets Manger in android. 
 [Follow this link](https://www.concretepage.com/android/android-assetmanager-example-to-load-image-from-assets-folder)
**Notice:**  `AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();` must be in youractvity.java file.

Comment: Requires bit fomatting