# Can't load image with Image Loader

Tags: java, android, database, android-volley, universal-image-loader

I want to set Image in CirculerImageView from the database with volley, But it's not working. (photo1 is TextView) and showing me in logcat:- E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /1541480944123.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

```
 String img_path = getString(R.string.imgpath);
                if (!photo1.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
                    String final_img_path = img_path + photo1.getText().toString();
                    Log.e("FINAL_IMAGE_PATH", final_img_path);
                    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(final_img_path, cimageview, options, animateFirstListener);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image not showing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
```

Comment: kindly provide the log.

Comment: E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /1541480944123.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42626505/unable-to-decode-stream-java-io-filenotfoundexception

Comment: please share the path which shows in textview

Comment: //abc.org/demosites/projectname/assets/uploads/

Comment: add http front of this path